# Postgresql error on bundle install

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, heroku, postgresql-9.1

I think this is a common problem, however the solutions I've found on the internet are not working for me. When I run bundle install with this section in my gemfile

```
group :production, :staging do
  gem "pg"
end

group :development, :test do
  gem "sqlite3-ruby", :require => "sqlite3"
end
```

I get the following error

```
creating Makefile

make
compiling gvl_wrappers.c
compiling pg.c
pg.c: In function ‘Init_pg_ext’:
pg.c:375: error: ‘PQPING_OK’ undeclared (first use in this function)
pg.c:375: error: (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once
pg.c:375: error: for each function it appears in.)
pg.c:377: error: ‘PQPING_REJECT’ undeclared (first use in this function)
pg.c:379: error: ‘PQPING_NO_RESPONSE’ undeclared (first use in this function)
pg.c:381: error: ‘PQPING_NO_ATTEMPT’ undeclared (first use in this function)
make: *** [pg.o] Error 1


Gem files will remain installed in /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/pg-0.16.0 for inspection.
Results logged to /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/pg-0.16.0/ext/gem_make.out
```

Next step, according to what I've found, is to run `locate pg_config`, then place the location after the `gem install pg`command line statement. However, I get this error instead:

```
WARNING: The locate database (/var/db/locate.database) does not exist.
To create the database, run the following command:

sudo launchctl load -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.locate.plist

Please be aware that the database can take some time to generate; once
the database has been created, this message will no longer appear.
```

I then run the `sudo` command, and get this final error....

```
launchctl: Couldn't stat("/System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.locate.plis"): No such file or directory
nothing found to load
```

This is my first attempt at using this technology, brand new to Mac as well. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

**EDIT**

I am trying to follow the suggestions [located here](https://gist.github.com/caike/6148957) regarding this error.

Comment: it's a .plist file, not .plis - You can use mdfind instead of locate on a mac. mdfind uses the mac os x spotlight database of files

Comment: Was able to track down the location of the pg_config file (`/usr/bin/pg_config`), however after adding this to the `gem install` statement still received the same error.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like despite what your gemfile says, you're trying to install postgres locally?

Really, that's what you should be doing.  It's really non-optimal to use a different database in production to the one you use locally.  I highly suggest just using Postgres everywhere, and remove sqlite.

On a Mac, the easiest route to this nirvana is to install [Postgress.app](http://postgresapp.com/)

Comment: Ok so.. I installed the Postgress.app from the link. Then ran all the commands from above (bundle install, locate pg.., etc) again and received the same error messages.

Comment: Hmm weird.  If you run it again, I'm going to guess that while installing the pg gem it's going to finish with something like "/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/pg-0.16.0/ext/foobar.out".  If it does, paste the output of foorbar.out here too..

Comment: By the way, the gist you point to suggests trying with 0.15.1.  I never had any problem with Ruby 2 and the pg gem - and I see I'm using  0.15.1.  Can you try changing your Gemfile so that it has the line `gem 'pg', '~> 0.15.1'` - save, and do a bundle install, and see what happens?